# Как сделать онлайн погрузку страницы

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Вот, возникла вот такая проблема.
Что бы вы её поняли придётся сильно много описывать.

Для примера возьмём социальную сеть Вконтакте.ком 
Там есть плеет, если я буду крутить вниз песни, то у меня будет автоматическая подгруздка страницы, как мне это сделать.
Если можно киньте ссылку на хороший урок

Comment: lazyload или ajax'ом это все дело подгружать

Comment: Поищите по словам `ajax scroll`. Найдёте в любом поисковике.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587210/load-more-posts-ajax-button-in-wordpress

Comment: Ловим событие onscroll . Поймали - если текущий скролл страницы превышает пороговую величину, делаем аякс-запрос, получающий следущую часть страницы. Сделали - вставляем ответ в конец, пороговая величина скролла увеличилась. Такая вот рекурсия.

Comment: Спасибо, что бы я делал без вашей помощи. Уже ночь я 2 месяц проект делаю, такую кучу технологий усвоил, вот точно мозг скоро из черепушки полезть ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По большей части все зависит от соответствующей логики на стороне сервера (php, ruby и тд), от этого будет зависеть какими именно способами лучше всего запрашивать, подгружать и оборачивать возвращаемые данные.

В данной ситуации речь очевидно идет о пагинации, которая часто реализуется get-запросом к серверу. Примером клиентского скрипта может быть что-то вроде этого:

```
function loadContent(link) {

    var http = createRequestObject();
    if( http ) {

        http.open('get', link);
        http.onreadystatechange = function () {

            if(http.readyState == 4) {

                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.innerHTML = http.responseText;
                var all = div.getElementsByTagName('div');

                for (var i = 0, len = all.length; i < len; i++) {

                   if (all[i] && all[i].getAttribute('id') == 'next-page-music-items-wrap') {

                      var deep = all[i].getElementsByClassName('next-page-music-item');
                      $('.current-page-music-items-wrap').append(deep);

                   }
                }
            }
        }

        http.send(null);

    } else {

        document.location = link;

    }
}

function createRequestObject() {
    try { return new XMLHttpRequest() }
    catch(e) {
        try { return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP') }
        catch(e) {

            try { return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') }
            catch(e) { return null; }
        }
    }
}
```